# Spring boot REST, only allow some property update

Tags: spring-boot

I'm creating a REST api in spring boot and currently I have a mapping to get a list of users and specific users.

Lets say my users looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John",
    "settings": [
        "show_ads": "true",
        "theme": "cool-black"
    ]
    "last_updated": "XXX",
    "created": "XXX"
}
```

Now I'm trying to create the update part of the crud interface.
How would I go about only allowing some field to be updated via the request body, but allowed to be seen at the GET path?

In this case I would allow name, show_ads and theme to be updated by the user.

I'm using oauth2 for authentication in front of the controllers, and I would like only for admins to be able to change some property values.

Also, when sending a request to update a user, does the request body need to be nested correctly?

```
PUT /users/1
{"name": "Peter", "show_ads": "false"} (1)
{"name": "Peter", "settings": ["show_ads": "false"]} (2)
```

Would both be valid or just number 2?

Comment: Post your Java code. Especially the entities. Tell us which properties you want to be read only.  Also in your json where you have squared brackets. They should be curly braces. I hope it's just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Two HTTP verbs are meant to be used for updates, [PUT and PATCH](http://www.baeldung.com/http-put-patch-difference-spring). PUT is defined to be idempotent, so only complete updates are valid. PATCH may be used for partial updates. Consider using [E-Tags](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#conditional.etag) in order to avoid conflicting (partial) updates.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The OP wants to know how he can prevent certain properties from being updatable. For example, let's say i have a `User` entity and not everyone should be able to edit their usernames, how can he prevent the `username` field from being edited. Using `PATCH` over `PUT` doesn't solve that issue.